# Lighthouse: Unable to run generate report on localhost

Tags: vue.js, lighthouse, nuxtjs

As the title says I'm trying to generate a report for my nuxt app served locally.
If I generate the report via DevTools it takes an extremely long time and gives me exceptionally bad scoring(compared to generating the report on the same site deployed).

If I try using the lighthouse extension the "Generate report" button is disabled.

Am I going about this wrong or is there any way to locally generate valid reports?

Thanks in advance.

Images:

[chrome extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrxoA.png)

[devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DgSY.png)

Answer (score 4):

Is your application PWA? Service workers are causing this. Try unchecking `clear storage` / `clear cache` option to the right of the window under the lighthouse tab, sometimes collapsed under a settings icon. If it's still not generating a report, do the same in an incognito window.

The issue:

[image]

The option:

[image]

[image]

And it works:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you're not trying lighthouse in incognito mode. Browser extensions can cause that problem.

- Click on the three dots under close button
- Select New Incognito Window
- Enter your website address
- Run lighthouse