# Light house not working in latest chrome version 95.0.4638.69

Tags: google-chrome, lighthouse

Light house not generating report in latest chrome browser.My browser was auto enabled for update.After updating the latest version, chrome not generating light house report.Its failed to generate the report only for performance.

**chrome version 95.0.4638.69**

Thanks

Comment: You don't list any information about the website/s you are trying to generate lighthouse reports for. FYI, I am also having the problem, for me, when testing locally, testing the site with a http url works, but https does not. Also, my site uses a webmanifest file and service worker. Voting to close this issue as it is next to useless and I am pretty sure it is a bug in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If it's PWA you're trying to generate a report on, probably caused by the service worker. Uncheck clear storage option under lighthouse. Linking an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70250990/11431068) for reference.